Custom Sign up page using Cognito attributes running into errors name.familyName is required
I created a custom sign up page and I'm using amplify and cognito. In cognito I'm using email, given_name and family_name but I keep getting this error below. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I couldn't find a sample sign up page that uses givenname and familyname. I created a test user manually and I can login so aws-exports.js seems to be working.
Error signing up: InvalidParameterException: Attributes did not conform to the schema: name.givenName: The attribute name.givenName is required, name.familyName: The attribute name.familyName is required

Required attributes
email
given_name
family_name
Here is my sign up page.
'use client';

import { useState } from 'react';
import { signUp } from 'aws-amplify/auth';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import Link from 'next/link';

export default function SignUp() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [given_name, setGivenName] = useState('');
  const [family_name, setFamilyName] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleSignUp = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await signUp({
        username: email,
        password,
        attributes: {
          email,
          given_name,
          family_name
        },
      });
      router.push('/login');
    } catch (err) {
      setError('Failed to sign up. Please try again.');
      console.error('Error signing up:', err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-50 py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div className="max-w-md w-full space-y-8">
        <div>
          <h2 className="mt-6 text-center text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900">
            Create your account
          </h2>
        </div>
        <form className="mt-8 space-y-6" onSubmit={handleSignUp}>
          <div className="rounded-md shadow-sm -space-y-px">
            <div>
              <input
                id="email"
                name="email"
                type="email"
                required
                className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-t-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
                placeholder="Email address"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <input
                id="password"
                name="password"
                type="password"
                required
                className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
                placeholder="Password"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <input
                id="given_name"
                name="given_name"
                type="text"
                required
                className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
                placeholder="Given name"
                value={given_name}
                onChange={(e) => setGivenName(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <input
                id="family_name"
                name="family_name"
                type="text"
                required
                className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-b-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
                placeholder="Family name"
                value={family_name}
                onChange={(e) => setFamilyName(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          {error && (
            <div className="text-red-500 text-sm mt-2">{error}</div>
          )}

          <div>
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="group relative w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
            >
              Sign Up
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div className="text-center">
          <Link href="/login" className="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500">
            Already have an account? Sign in
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


Your signUp payload seems to be wrong, you should use options for the user attributes.
import { signUp } from "aws-amplify/auth"

const { isSignUpComplete, userId, nextStep } = await signUp({
  username: "hello@mycompany.com",
  password: "hunter2",
  options: {  // <-- HERE !!!!
    userAttributes: {
      email: "hello@mycompany.com",
      given_name: "John",
      family_name: "Smith"
    },
  }
});


